# Pine Script v5, vwap (any) cross in backtesting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm building my strategy logic and my close condition is at VWAP cross, so:

```
longTP  = ta.cross(close, vwap)
shortTP = ta.cross(close, vwap)
```

In backtest I saw my OPs closes in the next bar open, which is fine knowing Tradingview limitation for intra bar calculations, but I got situations where VWAP is crossed many times by wicks and the OP doesn't close until SL is triggered.

SO I tried:

```
longTP  = ta.crossover(close, vwap)
shortTP = ta.crossunder(close, vwap)
```

then a very simple condition:

```
longTP  = close > vwap
shortTP = close < vwap
```

But all the above gave me the same results in backtesting.
I'm using `strategy.close()` like this:

```
if (LongTP)
    strategy.close(id="Long", qty_percent=100, comment="TP")
```

[image]

I try to minimize the abnormal results from my backtest to export data.

Answer (score 0):

`close` means close. Price must close above/below that level. This is not the case in your examples. The wicks cross the vwap line but price pulls back and closes below the line.

If you want to detect a wick cross, then use wicks in your condition.

```
longTP  = ta.crossover(high, vwap)
shortTP = ta.crossunder(low, vwap)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your recommendation improved many OPs but the issue still exists with wicks and bodies as well.